# LoadLibrary 998 error

Tags: c#, winapi, error-handling, loadlibrary

I have a .NET C# console app, which loads several Win32 DLL-s during runtime. When this app runs on my developer machine (32 bit Win7 on my laptop, 64 bit Win7 on my desktop comp), sometimes it causes 998 error. After rebooting the developer machines, this problem disappears. This happens on the test server (virtual machine on a linux, Win Server 2008 R2), but after restarting it disappears too. Not easy to reproduce for this reason.

Hard to understand the reason, when I the DLL-s load the dependecy walker, it shows absolutely no problem with them, the two dependecies are Kernel32.DLL and MSVCRT.DLL. Today this error happened starting my app from command line. I loaded the app into VS2010, and started, and the same dll-s was loaded without any problem. Stopping it I started my app from command line again, and it loaded the DLL-s too.

These DLL-s are developed not by me but a 3rd company, so I cannot see the source code of the DLL-s. Any idea of what happening?

Comment: Check this out, might help - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196069

Comment: Error 998 (`0x3e6`) is defined in `winerror.h` as `ERROR_NOACCESS`, `Invalid access to memory location`. A quick search of [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=ERROR_NOACCESS&ac=8) says this is caused by an access violation when `LoadLibrary` tries to load the DLL. There are a couple of KB articles there that might help.

Comment: Can you imagine an "invalid access to memory" which sometimes happens sometimes not?

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak: I can imagine it quite easily.  Happens all the time for a myriad of reasons.  I don't mean to be unhelpful, but we just don't have enough information to even begin to guess the cause. \

Comment: I asked the 3rd party developers, they said the DllMain contains a switch with no body, and a "return true;" (standard DllMain template).

Comment: Is there a possibility to debug the dll's DllMain to see what happens there? Using VS2010 or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

set you dll at the same folder your app in it.
your application must be run with administrator access right .
Just run the VS as Administrator 
or run the cmd as Administrator then change the cmd path to your app location as this example

```
c:\cd /d your_application_path
```

then write in the command prompt the name of your app .  then your application can have admin token to perform work successfully .